# What is the max length of a varchar (doctrine:string) in Doctrine 2 or SQL?

Tags: sql, doctrine

if i use a string type in doctrine 2 (maps to sql varchar), what is the max length i can use?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MySQL can save 65,535, others have the same limit. Oracle has 4000 as maximum limit (which is the lowest across all vendors!)

Answer (score 0):

In SQL the max length for VARCHAR is 255, same with TINYTEXT.

Reference: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/char.html

Comment: i shld say thats only in mysql 5.0.3 and below "The length can be specified as a value from 0 to 255 before MySQL 5.0.3, and 0 to 65,535 in 5.0.3 and later versions"